# Hibernate Search field mapping

Tags: hibernate, full-text-search, hibernate-search

The Hibernate Search @Field annotation gives the option to choose index name for a property:

```
...
@Field(name="somethingOrOther")
public String getSomeValue() {
...
```

The user guide says this about the name property of the @Field annotation:

> name : describe under which name, the property should be stored in the
>   Lucene Document. The default value is the property name (following the
>   JavaBeans convention)

Is there any way to set the name to another value from the annotated bean?

Something like

```
...
public String getFieldName() {
   return fieldName;
}

@Field(name="{fieldName}")
public String getFieldValue() {
   return fieldValue;
}
```

where {fieldName} will be replaced with the result of getFieldName().

Comment: Checked out the source, seems it cannot be done.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done using a custom *FieldBridge*. When implementing the FieldBridge interface your own code is responsible for adding the value to the Lucene Document, so in practice you can write whatever you want.

[FieldBridge documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.3/reference/en-US/html_single/#example-field-bridge)

Comment: Thanks! That would have done the trick (I think, I don't remember the exact use case). As it was I found another way to do what I needed.